# Kentico 11 Accessing Session Variables on Session End

Tags: session, kentico

we are trying to access the session variables on session end.  We have created a new module called ApplicationSessionEventsHandlerModule and added a SessionEnd_Execute handler.

However, the Kentico SessionHelper class does not work and neither does System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.  How do you recommend we access session variables on session end?  See code:

```
  public class ApplicationSessionEventsHandlerModule : Module
    {
    public ApplicationSessionEventsHandlerModule() :
        base("ApplicationSessionEventsHandlerModule")
        {
        }

    protected override void OnInit()
        {
        base.OnInit();
        ApplicationEvents.SessionStart.Execute += SessionStart_Execute;
        ApplicationEvents.SessionEnd.Execute += SessionEnd_Execute;
        }

    private void SessionEnd_Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        if (SessionHelper.SessionIsAvailable)
            {
            if (SessionHelper.GetValue("UserDetails") != null)
                {
               //Do stuff
                    }
                }

            }


    private void SessionStart_Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        if (SessionHelper.GetValue("UserDetails") != null)
            {
          //do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference link - https://docs.xperience.io/k11/custom-development/handling-global-events/reference-global-system-events#ReferenceGlobalsystemevents-ApplicationEvents

Please try the following -

1. Create a Global folder under \App_Code\
2. Create a ApplicationSessionEventsHandler.cs file under Global folder with the following code snippet and try -

   ```
    using CMS.Base;
    using CMS.DocumentEngine;
    using CMS.Helpers;
    using CMS.Membership;

    [ApplicationSessionEventsHandler]
    public partial class CMSModuleLoader
    {
    public class ApplicationSessionEventsHandler : CMSLoaderAttribute
    {
    public override void Init()
    {
    ApplicationEvents.SessionEnd.Execute += SessionEnd_Execute;
    ApplicationEvents.SessionStart.Execute += SessionStart_Execute;

    }

    private void SessionStart_Execute(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    if (SessionHelper.GetValue("UserDetails") != null)
    {
    //do stuff
    }
    }
    private void SessionEnd_Execute(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    if (SessionHelper.SessionIsAvailable)
    {
    if (SessionHelper.GetValue("UserDetails") != null)
    {
    //Do stuff
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
   ```

Comment: I tried this but it seems as though the CMSLoaderAttribute class does not exist.  Is there an updated solution for v11?